# Cannot find few files in alfresco installation directory

Tags: java, alfresco, hit-highlighting

I installed Alfresco Community edition 3.4d inorder to give hit highlighting. I am following this particular blog http://aymen-s.blogspot.in/. But I cannot find few files mentioned in the blog

1. /DataModel/source/java/org/alfresco/service/cmr/dictionary/PropertyDefinition.java
   /DataModel/source/java/org/alfresco/repo/dictionary/M2Property.java 
   /DataModel/source/java/org/alfresco/repo/dictionary/m2binding.xml
   /DataModel/source/java/org/alfresco/repo/dictionary/M2PropertyDefinition.java
   /Repository/source/java/org/alfresco/repo/search/impl/lucene/index/IndexInfo.java
   /Repository/source/java/org/alfresco/repo/search/impl/lucene/ADMLuceneIndexerImpl.java
   /Repository/source/java/org/alfresco/repo/search/impl/lucene/AVMLuceneIndexerImpl.java
   /DataModel/source/java/org/alfresco/service/cmr/search/ResultSetSPI.java
   /Repository/source/java/org/alfresco/repo/search/impl/lucene/LuceneResultSet.java
   /DataModel/source/java/org/alfresco/service/cmr/search/ResultSetRow.java
   /Repository/source/java/org/alfresco/repo/search/AbstractResultSetRow.java
   /Repository/source/java/org/alfresco/repo/jscript/ScriptNode.java
   /Repository/source/java/org/alfresco/repo/jscript/Search.java
   /Remote
   API/config/alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/slingshot/search/search.lib.js
   /Remote
   API/config/alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/slingshot/search/search.get.json.ftl
   /Slingshot/source/web/components/search/search.js
   /Slingshot/source/web/components/search/search.css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The files which you are mentioning are part of source code of alfresco you will not be able to find most of them under installation as java files will be part of jar files.
For finding those files you need to checkout alfresco source code from repository from given link mentioned in the blog.[(SVN PATCH)](http://db.tt/FGq1bwm)

Comment: Okay so I need to download the source code and modify them, but after modifying them how can I add them to my installation?